# What is the correct JSON syntax for adding an "event" to a custom item in a Minecraft Bedrock behavior pack as of v. 1.20.30?

Tags: javascript, json, minecraft

*NOTICE: This question is asking about a removed feature which no longer works. As originally asked, the question is no longer answerable. However, there is a workaround which solves the same problem (implementing custom tool durabilities) here on Arquade.SE: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/405593/306012.*

---

**Q:** What is the correct syntax for an **event** to be called by a custom tool's `"on_dig"` method in the `.item.json` file with `"format_version"` 1.20.30?

---

I'm working on a Minecraft Bedrock resource and behavior pack set, which contains custom copper tools. These are meant to function just like the vanilla tools, but with speed/durability values between those of stone and iron. **They should have a durability bar which decreases as they're used to break blocks or damage entities.**

**Currently, the tools' durability will only decrease when they are used as a weapon** (this happens automatically - no custom event required). Breaking blocks does *not* automatically cause wear to the tools, whether or not the blocks being broken are listed in  the `"destroy_speeds"` property of the `"minecraft:digger"` component. I believe it is *intended* to work automatically[?], but this feature appears to be currently broken, so I'm trying to implement a workaround using a custom event.

Unfortunately, it's difficult to find up-to-date documentation for **items** in **1.20.30**, which is the latest stable version: I'm not using experimental features in this pack.  The [official Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/reference/content/itemreference/examples/itemcomponentlist) has full tutorials for adding custom **entities** and **blocks**, but the **item** documentation is less complete -- all components are described, but *examples of the correct syntax to use for the properties' values are often absent* (it just says "JSON Object"). I found [a different source here](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/items/tool-durability.html) which gives an example of a custom tool with a durability-decrementing event, but it appears that it is out of date (1.16.100). Now, attempting to use the same syntax gives this error in the console:

`[Item][error]-addtns:copper_pickaxe.increment_item_wear | damage | child 'damage' not valid here.`

and the event also does not work.

Aside from this issue, the custom pickaxe works as intended. Here is the complete copper_pickaxe.item.json file from the behavior pack:

```
{  
  "format_version": "1.20.30",  
  "minecraft:item": {  
        "description": {  
            "identifier": "addtns:copper_pickaxe",  
            "menu_category": {  
                "group": "itemGroup.name.pickaxe",
                "category": "equipment"
            }  
        },  
        "components": {  
            "minecraft:damage": 4, // Same as for iron
            "minecraft:max_stack_size": 1,
            "minecraft:icon": {  
                "texture": "copper_pickaxe"  
            },  
            "minecraft:hand_equipped": true,  
            "minecraft:display_name": {  
                "value": "Copper Pickaxe"  
            },
            "minecraft:digger": {
                "destroy_speeds": [ // The copper pickaxe should be able to obtain all the same materials as a stone pickaxe, plus redstone
                    {
                        //"block": {"tags":"q.any_tag('stone','metal','stone_pick_diggable')"}, // stone_pick_diggable doesn't seem to be working
                        "block": {"tags":"q.any_tag('stone','metal')"},
                        "speed": 5 // Same speed as iron?
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:copper_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:coal_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:tuff",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:iron_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:redstone_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:lit_redstone_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:lapis_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:redstone_block",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_coal_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_copper_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_iron_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_redstone_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:lit_deepslate_redstone_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_lapis_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "addtns:echo_block",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:cobbled_deepslate",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:chiseled_deepslate",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_bricks",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:cracked_deepslate_bricks",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:deepslate_tiles",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:cracked_deepslate_tiles",
                        "speed": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "block": "minecraft:quartz_ore",
                        "speed": 5
                    }
                ],
                "use_efficiency": true,
                "on_dig": {
                    // The event definition (see bottom of file) gives the error "child damage is not valid here"
                    "event": "addtns:copper_pickaxe.increment_item_wear"
                }
            },
            "minecraft:durability": { // NOT WORKING - a known unresolved issue? https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-100344
                // Item is supposed to always take damage when used (100% chance).
                // Instead, nothing happens when it is used to mine, and it only takes damage when used as a weapon.
                // Uncommenting the explicit min & max values doesn't fix this.
                //"damage_chance": {
                    //"min": 100,  
                    //"max": 100
                //},
                "max_durability": 200 // Between stone (132) and iron (251) - see stats here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe
            },
            "minecraft:repairable": {
                "repair_items": [
                    {
                        "items": ["copper_ingot"],
                        "repair_amount": 67 // Repair 1/3 of item's total durability per copper ingot
                    }
                ]
            },
            "minecraft:enchantable": {
                "slot": "pickaxe",
                "value": 10
            }
        },
        // Reference: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/items/custom-weapon.html
        "events": {
            "addtns:copper_pickaxe.increment_item_wear": { // No longer correct syntax?
                "damage": {
                    "type": "durability",
                    "target": "self",
                    "amount": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `events`, it should be `addtns:copper_pickaxe.on_dig_damage`.

Comment: The `"on_dig"` component has now been removed, so any solutions involving it are no longer current. Instead, refer to this question and answer on Arquade.SE: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405592/item-component-on-dig-has-been-removed-how-to-handle-tool-durability-in-new for a working solution which does not use this component.